# VSCode Auto Import inconsistency

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working in a JS project and having difficulties with using the Auto Import feature.  The function that I want to have automatically imported is located at "../utils/htmlDOMFuncs" and is named setSelectedVisit.  If I start typing the name of the function, I don't get any kind of autocomplete.  If I then open another file in my project that does already have something imported from "../utils/htmlDOMFuncs", then I do see the function name in my autocomplete suggestions.  However, upon first hitting tab, the function is not added as an import to the top of the current file.  If I then hit backspace and re-type the rest of the function name, I do then see the additional tooltip showing information about the function and where it will be auto imported from.  Is this the correct behavior?

A few images to illustrate.
- [Typing into file, no other files opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42gD0.png)
- [With another file opened that already imports the module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIQRO.png)
- [After having used the autocomplete, then deleting and re-typing, I see the Auto Import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1yaZ.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely need to create a [`jsconfig.json` file](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-project-jsconfigjson) at the root of your workspace with the contents:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/node_modules/*"
    ]
}
```

This file tells VS Code to treat all js files in your workspace as part of the same project

Comment: Thank you!  I always thought that VSCode would default to interpreting a project as a JS project unless it found reasons otherwise.  I see now on the link that the documentation clearly states that often times it is not required, but may be needed.  Appreciate your quick response.

Comment: I'm wondering why this isn't the default behavior. Creating a such file for every project and adding it to gitignore seems redundant.